# Accessing the memory with different access sizes

Tags: memory, low-level, instruction-set, memory-access

I am currently working on a project, where i inject bitflips (0 -> 1, or 1 -> 0) in memory or registers. Now i have to think about some special cases.

Here is my question: 
Can there be cases, where there is a memory access on a certain memory location and shortly after, there is a memory access on the same location with smaller or wider access size?

Example:

```
1:    ld.B    D15, [A15]
2:    ld.W    D15, [A15]
```

In line 1 the memory is accessed via the pointer in the addressregister A15 and it's content is stored in dataregister D15. The access size is a byte (.B).
In line 2 it's the same as in line 1, but with the access size word (.W)(32-Bit).

So the access sizes would be something like this:

```
[A15]  ------XX  -> line 1
[A15]  XXXXXXXX  -> line 2
```

Where X is a hexdecimal.

Is this possible, that the compiler would do something like this? And what would be an example case for this?

I have no idea if this question is stupid or not. I am sorry! :D

Comment: Narrow stores and a wide reload (or vice versa) could easily happen in an endian-conversion function that compiled inefficiently.  A compiler could plausibly generate a byte load and a word load from the same value, maybe for `x` and `x&0xff`, but not to the same destination register without having used it first.  Most compilers would normally prefer to use an ALU instruction like AND or a bit-field extract / zero-extend instruction to use one load result two ways, though.  With `volatile` you could certain construct C that compiled to separate loads if you wanted to.

Comment: Very nice, thank you for your information! I am going to try to create a case like this!